# Variable returning empty

Tags: c#, variables, null, collectionview

I have a CollectionView and inside it I have a method which reads files from a location and once read, are meant to add it to the variables. This is my code:

```
class Cvs
{
    static string x1, x2, x3;
    public class Items
    {
        public string ItemID { get; set; }
        public string ItemTitle { get; set; }
        public string ItemBody { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemList
    {
        List<Items> item = new List<Items>();
        public ItemList()
        {
            ReadStuff();

            item.Add(new Items() { ItemID = x1, ItemTitle = x2, ItemBody = x3 });
        }
        public List<Items> GetitemList()
        {
            return item;
        }
    }

    public async static void ReadStuff()
    {
        var AppStorage = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var itemFolders = await AppStorage.GetFolderAsync(@"App\Folder\");
        var Items = await itemFolders.GetFoldersAsync();
        foreach (var itemFolder in Items)
        {
            var itemTitle = await AppStorage.GetFileAsync(string.Format(@"App\Folder\{0}\Title.txt", itemFolder.Name));
            var itemBody = await AppStorage.GetFileAsync(string.Format(@"App\Folder\{0}\Body.txt", itemFolder.Name));

            var itemReadTitle = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(itemTitle);
            var itemReadBody = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(itemBody);

            x1 = itemFolder.Name;
            x2 = itemReadTitle;
            x3 = itemReadBody;
        }
    }
}
```

What it's supposed to do is read those files and when it does it's meant to add it into the `x1`, `x2` and `x3` and then `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are added to the:

```
item.Add(new Items() {ItemID = x1, ItemTitle = x2, ItemBody = x3});
```

the end result is empty even though the files aren't empty. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You not await for ReadStuff()

```
public ItemList()
{
    Initialize();
}

public async void Initialize()
{
    await ReadStuff();
    item.Add(new Items() { ItemID = x1, ItemTitle = x2, ItemBody = x3 });
}
```

You must change ReadStuf from void to Task

Comment: I cannot add the async to `public async ItemList()` because it doesn't allow mt to add it in the constructor.

Comment: @F4z You should use ReadStuff().Wait(); in constructor, but it is not good practice. You can have an empty constructor and call Initialize after object create.

Answer (score 0):

1) You must `await` ReadStuff()

2) Because `ReadStuff` is iterating, setting statics (the x variables) will not work. Change the `ReadStuff` to also add the item to the list.

```
public async static void ReadStuff(List<Items> items)
{
    var AppStorage = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var itemFolders = await AppStorage.GetFolderAsync(@"App\Folder\");
    var Items = await itemFolders.GetFoldersAsync();
    foreach (var itemFolder in Items)
    {
        var itemTitle = await AppStorage.GetFileAsync(string.Format(@"App\Folder\{0}\Title.txt", itemFolder.Name));
        var itemBody = await AppStorage.GetFileAsync(string.Format(@"App\Folder\{0}\Body.txt", itemFolder.Name));

        var itemReadTitle = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(itemTitle);
        var itemReadBody = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(itemBody);

        x1 = itemFolder.Name;
        x2 = itemReadTitle;
        x3 = itemReadBody;

       items.Add(new Items() { ItemID = x1, ItemTitle = x2, ItemBody = x3 });
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot add the async to `public async ItemList()` because it doesn't allow mt to add it in the constructor. How would I add the items within the method when it's exclusive to just that one constructor which is : `public ItemList()

Comment: Just got your updated answer. Ill let you know in a bit

Comment: Change ReadStuff to accept the list as an argument.

Comment: It doesn't work properly. For some reason. It loads the items however doesn't load everything. I have to restart the app and still wouldn't load everything.

Comment: Perhaps its the `async` logic in a constructor.  Try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: Removing the 'async' will give me errors where I've used the 'await' method.

Comment: Yes you need to remove the `await`s also, because they are being called  by the constructor.

Comment: The problem is if I remove the await, the 'AppStorage.GetFileAsync'..will not work. I'm using WinRT and these are the only ways(to my knowledge) to read and create etc.